# Does material-ui v1 work with react v16

Tags: material-ui

I am currently using React 16 and I would like to try material v1.  I was wondering if Material-ui v1 works with React v16.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the current release of v1 lists React 16.0.0-beta.5 as a peer dependency (from [package.json](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/package.json)):

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0-beta.5"
  },
```